# manually importing tableauserverclient module without pip install

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am manually importing tableauserverclient to my python script with doing a pip install. Based on https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/ documentation , its recommended to do a pip install. However , there are restriction in my server to have this module installed with pip. Therefor i am manually transferring this files.  On my local machine, when i do pip install,

```
import tableauclientserver as TSC
```

works perfectly fine, without having any error. When i manually download the zip file and extract tableauserverclient folder and transfer this to my server. Its showing me error

Folder structure

```
path: /home/project1/poc
 - poc.py [python file]
 - tableauserverclient [folder]
```

poc.py

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
print('Success')
```

The error im receiving is

```
  File "poc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tableauserverclient as TSC
  File "/home/project1/poc/tableauserverclient/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .server import (
  File "/home/project1/poc/tableauserverclient/server/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .request_factory import RequestFactory
  File "/project1/poc/tableauserverclient/server/request_factory.py", line 3, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField
```

I am currently running python 3.8.7 on server which are required to run tableauserverclient.  I have tried researching on this error but i couldnt find any .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say you can't use pip, you mean that you can't download the application through pip, not that you can't run pip at all. The instructions for using it [offline](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/#install-on-an-offline-machine) say

1. Ensure that Python 3.5 or higher is installed.
2. Download and manually install the requests Python library (and its dependencies).
3. Download the setup package.
4. Run pip install ./tableauserverclient-x.y.tar.gz

It sounds like you have missed the step to install the requests library. You can download it from [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install/#install) and then install it with pip from the download.